App Service looses connection to SQL Server via VNET
I have a Linux App Service and a SQL Server. The App Service needs to connect to the SQL DB. Both resources are integrated in a VNET which has two subnets:

default (Service Endpoints: Microsoft.Web, Microsoft.Sql; Delegation: none) -> SQL Server
webApp (Service Endpoints: Microsoft.Web, Microsoft.Sql; Delegation: serverFarms) -> App Service

My networking settings for SQL Server are:

Public access: disabled
Private access: private endpoint (VNET -> default)

Everything works as expected but just for a random amount of time (minutes - days). After that time, my App Service is not able to connect to the SQL Server anymore. The exception is the following:

Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
(0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

2024-09-12T11:05:35.8086896Z Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8087667Z  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8087732Z    at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses, AddressFamily addressFamily, Nullable`1 startingTimestamp)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8087778Z    at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress, AddressFamily family)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8087840Z    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNICommon.GetDnsIpAddresses(String serverName)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8087960Z    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.Connect(String serverName, Int32 port, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean isInfiniteTimeout, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference, String cachedFQDN, SQLDNSInfo& pendingDNSInfo)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088009Z    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle..ctor(String serverName, Int32 port, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean parallel, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference, String cachedFQDN, SQLDNSInfo& pendingDNSInfo, Boolean tlsFirst, String hostNameInCertificate, String serverCertificateFilename)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088048Z    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088096Z    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088140Z    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088210Z    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088258Z    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088304Z    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088362Z    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088410Z    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088476Z    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088524Z    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternaloldConnection)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088568Z    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088624Z    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088659Z    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088906Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8088981Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089031Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089080Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089131Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089177Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089226Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089300Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089352Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089400Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089454Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089507Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreatedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089555Z    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreatedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089607Z    at [...].Data.DbInitializer.InitializeAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in C:\[...].cs:line 17
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089669Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_1(Object state)
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089713Z    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
2024-09-12T11:05:35.8089757Z    at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()

That also happened after an App Service Plan upgrade.
What might be the reason?

It might be that you've only just now upgraded to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version 4 or later, which is significantly pickier about self-signed certificates and changes the default connection encryption settings. (Version 5 bumps this up a notch, too.) Do you have a full stack trace to go along with the exception message?

I have added the full stack trace to my post. It seems like a DNS issue? But why does it occur after a random amount of time? I am able to "fix" this temporary by removing the private endpoint and adding it again.

Does it working after Reading Private Endpoint?

What do you mean by "Read Private Endpoint"? It is working, when i remove & re-add the private endpoint via azure portal for the sql server.

Hi @JanMöller, I mean Remove and Re-adding private endpoint for the resource.


App Service loses connection to SQL Server via VNET

In general, the error which you mentioned is due to incomplete configuration of private endpoint or might be due to issue in referencing the incorrect private endpoint.
As VenkatV mentioned we need to recreate a private end point and refer it again with the correct one.

Removing and readding the private endpoint will trigger an update to DNS records associate with endpoints this will make sure if there any expired DNS entries get removed and updated with new one and this approach will also resets the connection.
Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/troubleshoot-private-endpoint-connectivity
